# Save additional fields to Rails child model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parent-child

I have two models: `Donor` and `Gift`. I've created `has_many` and `belongs_to` associations. In my `DonorsController` class, I have -

def new
    @donor = Donor.new
    gift = @donor.gifts.build
  end

This is defined in DonorsController -

```
def create    
  @donor = Donor.new(donation_params)
... etc....
end

private

  def donation_params
    params.require(:donor).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :address_1, :address_2, :city, :state, :zip, :email, :phone, gifts_attributes: [:amount, :frequency])
  end
```

I want to save the `charge.id` that I get back from Stripe after processing a payment, I'm trying it with this -

`@donor.gifts.stripe_charge_id = charge.id` (I also tried singular gift - didn't help).

`@donor.save` works just fine - including the gift fields that are on the form and in the permitted list - they all get saved to the db. But the `stripe_charge_id` field is blank. I've confirmed there is a `charge.id` value.

`@donor.stripe_customer_id = customer.id` is working.

I added `cattr_accessor :stripe_charge_id` to the `Gift` model.

I've tried defining set/get methods, nothing is working.

Any help would be appreciated. Everything I've googled just expounds on parent & child associations, but I don't have any problems with that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @donor.gifts.stripe_charge_id = charge.id. `gifts` is a `has_many` relation, so, you can't assign `gifts.stripe_charge_id` because `gifts` is a collection. You would need to iterate through all the gifts and assign them the `charge.id`. That's one way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @fanta said, you have a `has_many` relation. So you cannot set the `stripe_charge_id` like that. And even if you did it right, rails would not save the child just because you saved the parent.

You could do this:

```
@donor.gifts.update_all(:stripe_charge_id => charge.id)
```

Comment: Thank you for the replies. It is a has_many relationship, because a donor can potentially have more than one gift, but there's one for each transaction. The other gift fields get saved on the donor save method without any additional code, so I was thinking I could add the stripe_charge_id prior to saving the donor. But I called the update_all function after saving the donor and that did it. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi - I voted but my score is still too low for it to be reflected in the score - sorry.